# Add string array to comma separated words

Tags: php, arrays

My array:

```
preg_match_all('/<title>.*?<\/title>/is', $content, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);

Array
(
    [0] => lorem
    [1] => ipsum
    [2] => dolor
    [3] => sit
)

$impl = implode(", ", array_values(array_unique($matches[0])));
echo $impl; // lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit
```

I want it to be automatically added into `array()` function, something look like:

```
$rest = array("lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit");
```

Comment: So you want `$impl = array_unique($matches[0]));`?

Answer (score 1):

i think you just want  as the question title says a string so all you have to do for all your array which look like $matches[0] is:

```
$impl = implode(", ", array_map(function($v){return '"'.$v.'"';},array_values(array_unique($matches[0]))));


function just_wrap_in_array($string){
    $start='array(';
    $end=');';
    return is_string($string)?$start.$string.$end:false;
}
echo just_wrap_in_array($impl);//array("lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want $rest to be an array of words, just do:

`$rest = $matches[0];`

You already have the array.

Comment: But the result is back to :  `Array ([0] => lorem [1] => ipsum [2] => dolor[3] => sit)`. I want it to become `array("lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit");`

Comment: Which is exactly what you would get if you did `$rest = array("lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit");`

Comment: @RomeoLeGagahne I don't think you understand how arrays work in php. ([0] => lorem, [1] => ipsum, ... ) is exactly the same as ("lorum", "ipsum", ...).

Comment: @ChadK i think what Romeo LeGagahne want is a string as the title says...